# How to find Coefficients in Logistic regression?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, loss-function, gradient-descent

I am trying to find coefficients in Logistic regression

code:

```
def fit(self, X, Y):

    # number of data points in the dataset (number of rows)  -->  m
    # number of input features in the dataset (number of columns)  --> n
    self.m, self.n = X.shape

    self.no_of_iterations=1000

    #initiating weight & bias value

    self.w = np.zeros(self.n)
    
    self.b = 0

    self.X = X

    self.Y = Y


    # implementing Gradient Descent for Optimization

    for i in range(self.no_of_iterations):     
      self.update_weights()



  def update_weights(self):

    # Y_hat formula (sigmoid function)

    Y_hat = 1 / (1 + np.exp( - (self.X.dot(self.w) + self.b ) ))    


    # derivaties

    dw = (1/self.m)*np.dot(self.X.T, (Y_hat - self.Y))

    db = (1/self.m)*np.sum(Y_hat - self.Y)


    # updating the weights & bias using gradient descent

    self.w = self.w - self.learning_rate * dw

    self.b = self.b - self.learning_rate * db
```

i go through lot of articles, Those takes no.of iterations 1000. why 1000?

what happened if takes more or less iteration?

How to choose No.of iterations?

if take 1000 iterations, whatever values get in 1000 iteration we are using those to predict,
how we know that value  is the best ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no general answer to your question, it depends on lots of factors.
A good indication is given by observing the value of the loss functions on the training/validation datasets.

In the ideal case scenario, what happens it that:

- as you go on with training, your model will keep learning on your
  training data, so that the training loss on that set will go down;
- hopefully, the model will also be able to generalize to new data (data you're NOT using for training), so that the ***loss function on the validation set*** will go down as well. As a rule of thumb, you can expect the loss on validation data to be always higher than the one on training data (the model will be always better on training data, because that's what it's trying to reproduce);
- at a certain point, you'll notice that the training loss will keep decreasing, while the validation one will plateau, or even start increasing again. That's a sign of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), i.e. your model is getting too much...tailored on the training data, and it's losing its generalization capabilities. That's a good point to stop your training.

[image: train/validation losses]

How fast this happens (i.e., after how many iterations it happens) depends on lots of factors, but it can be greatly influenced by your learning rate. Higher learning rate will make the model learn faster (the overfitting point is reached after fewer iterations), while with a lower one it'll take longer.
On the other hand, watch out, because if the learning rate is *too high* you could find yourself in a situation where the model is not learning at all, which is indicated by the fact that the training loss doesn't decrease, or even increases.
You can take a look at this picture to get the idea (this is only the training loss for different learning rates):

[image: learning rate]

This is a very summarized explanation, so I would suggest you look into this stuff more yourself. You can find lots of material online (probably, even too much), I always suggest [Andrew Ng's machine learning introductory course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome). The course is free, and the dude is amazingly good in explaining this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Gradient descent solvers can overshoot, i.e. the step a little bit to far to get convergence. Restricting the number of iterations shortcuts the problem.
You can use the `learning rate`  with a fixed rate to get another solution for the problem. Setting it to 1/2 ("step halving") can help to mitigate the problem.

Moreover you should rather check for convergence. That is define some small epsilon and check if the change in the target is smaller than that. If it the case stop iterating.

Another general hint: Although logistic regression problems are (in theory) generally well behaved you can run for large numbers of coefficients and observations into condition problems, that means your derivatives become NaNs:
You need to check this.

I assume this is an excercise for learning or something. For production purposes it is always better to use a well tested solution as scikit-learn  in python or a glm in R.